# Калькулятор на js

Tags: javascript, html

Решил как начинающий разработчик сделать калькулятор.Есть много примеров (но вот сейчас не могу найти), когда человек выбирает скажем дверь. Т.е. в первом ряду есть выбор цвета

- красный
- белый
- синий

потом человек выбирает покрытие

- дуб
- бамбук
- краска

и на конец выбирает толщину

- 1
- 2
- 3

Ну потом есть ещё пару инпутов и селектов - но по ним вопросов нет - там просто внутри ф-ции берется их значение `document.getelementbyid('q').value`
и складываются или умножаются. А вот с выбором цвета не могу понять как делать. Ну вот получается у меня такой html

```
    <form> 
<div class="l1">
    <div id="q11" value="1">красный </div>
    <div id="q12" value="2">Белый</div>
    <div id="q13" value="3">Синий</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>        
<div class="l2">
    <div id="q21" value="1">дуб</div>
    <div id="q22" value="2">бамбук</div>
    <div id="q23" value="3">краска</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>  
<div class="l2">
    <div id="q31" value="1">1</div>
    <div id="q32" value="2">2</div>
    <div id="q33" value="3">3</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div> 
<input type="submit" onclick="f()">
</form>
```

Вопрос 1 - как мне сделать так что бы при нажатии на "красный" он скажем обводился красным border  - вешать на все параметры `onclick`?
Вопрос 2 - как мне брать значения выделенного параметра? Т.е. мне нужно под каждый параметр создать переменную типа `var x = document.getelementbyid('q').value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой ответ может показать сложным, если вы новичок, но зато он будет более структурированным, да и вам на будущее пригодиться.

Для начала представим себе дверь - что это такое? Это объект, с какими-то свойствами и возможностями ( методами )

У нас есть 3 свойства: цвет, покрытие, толщина
У нас должно быть две возможности ( метода ): показать дверь, изменить свойство двери

Вот наш объект ( если незнакомы с ООП в JS, [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/objects-more) все объясняют легко )

```
var door = {
    color : "#000", // изначально черный цвет пусть будет
    weight : 10, // по умолчанию
    cover : "" // наше покрытие, пока его нет
}
```

Св-ва объекту мы добавили, теперь методы

```
door.render = function () { /* рисуем дверь */ };
door.changeProperty = function (prop, value) {
    this[prop] = value;
    this.render(); // отрисовываем изменившуюся дверь
}
```

Зачем все это? А вот зачем, теперь очень легко изменять значения, и она сразу же будут отображаться

```
<div class="l1">
    <div id="q11" onclick='door.changeProperty("color", "red")'>красный </div>
    <div id="q12" onclick='door.changeProperty("color", "#fff")'>Белый</div>
    <div id="q13" onclick='door.changeProperty("color", "blue")'>Синий</div>
</div>
```

В ф-ции `door.render();` делаейте что хотите, все свойства находятся в переменной `this[/*имя свойства*/]`. Например, изменить цвет рамки

```
door.render = function () {
    var el; // ссылка на html элемент, который является нашей дверью
    el.style.borderColor = this.color;
}
```

[Рабочий пример](http://output.jsbin.com/xafexivefi)

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ, не особо сложно, но всё же есть над чем подумать.